# How to get all the markers associated with a specific function in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

There are many ways to mark a test function in pytest, for example:

- Define module level markers in module level with `pytestmark = [...,...]`
- Define class and function level markers with `@pytest.mark`

Suppose There is a function `test_do_some_stuff_based_on_markers()` which needs to get all the markers associated with this function and do some stuff, for example:

test_file.py:

```
pytestmark = [pytest.mark.module_marker]


@pytest.mark.class_marker
class TestClassA:
    @pytest.mark.func_marker
    def test_do_some_stuff_based_on_markers(self)
        all_markers = <a_function_that_gets_all_the_markers_above>
```

And I need a function which can get me all the markers associated with this function, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `request` parameter to the test function and collect the markers from the `node` attributes

```
pytestmark = [pytest.mark.module_marker]


@pytest.mark.class_marker
class TestClassA:
    @pytest.mark.func_marker
    def test_do_some_stuff_based_on_markers(self, request):
        markers = [mark.name for mark in request.node.module.pytestmark] +\
                  [mark.name for mark in request.node.cls.pytestmark] +\
                  [mark.name for mark in request.node.own_markers]
        print(markers) # ['module_marker', 'class_marker', 'func_marker']
```

Comment: This exactly solved my problem, thank you!